# The method implicitly changes the value of the class member

Tags: c++

**Screen.h**

```
#include "Diagonal/Diagonal.h"

class Screen {
public:
    Screen(const unsigned short _height) { // Constructor for diagonal initializing
        Diagonal diagonal{_height};
        this->diagonal = &diagonal;
    }

    Diagonal* diagonal{}; // Diagonal declaration

private:

};
```

**Diagonal.h**

```
struct Diagonal {
public:
    Diagonal() = default; // Default constructor

    Diagonal(const unsigned short _length) // Length initializing constructor
        : length{ _length } {}

    unsigned short get_length() const { // Get value of length
        return length;
    }

    const unsigned short length; // Screen length
private:

};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../Core/Headers/Screen/Screen.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    system("mode con cols=80 lines=162"); // Setting up the terminal's cols and lines
    MoveWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0, 0, 1400, 1000, true); // Setting up th terminal position when starts

    Screen* screen = new Screen{162};
    
    std::cout << screen->diagonal->length << std::endl;
    std::cout << screen->diagonal->get_length() << std::endl;
    std::cout << screen->diagonal->length << std::endl;

    delete screen;
}
```

I created the object `screen`. Using the `Screen` constructor and then `Diagonal` I initialized the `Diagonal` member - `length`. When I tried to print `length` through the object, the program behaved predictably, but when through the `Diagonal` method, the value of the `length` was implicitly changed and the output was this:

`162`

`32759`

`32759`

but should be this:

`162`

`162`

`162`

I tried to rewrite method `get_length()` using pointers, using parameter `Dialog* dialog`(must be pointer) and tried to combine... Tried to find the solution or ideas for this problem, but the result of the program hasn't changed.

Comment: `Diagonal diagonal{_height}; this->diagonal = &diagonal;` -- You are storing a pointer to a local variable.  What do you think happens when that local variable goes out of scope?

Comment: Check your nose to make sure demons aren't flying out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Screen.h Constructor**

```
Screen(const unsigned short _height) { // Constructor for diagonal initializing
        Diagonal diagonal{_height};
        this->diagonal = &diagonal;
    }
```

I am storing a pointer to a local variable.

Thank you, [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie)!